# How to open a program via MS Office Power Point 2010?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I'd like to know if is possible to open a program by clicking a link on a Power Point 2010 slide, I know that is possible to open a video from the slide but what about a program, is possible to link it from the slide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a hyperlink to a PowerPoint slide and point it to an EXE file which will then launch the program.  Highlight the text you want to use as a link and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to open the hyperlink window.  Browse to your program and press OK to insert the link.

Be aware that you will get at least one or two warnings about opening potentially dangerous links:

[image: Warning #1]
[image: Warning #2]

As long as you know the program and where it is launching from, you should be safe.